# Spark / Kafka Streaming : write a single file per hour

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I tried to write a single parquet file (one per hour) from data coming from kafka, instead of it, spark wrote a bunch of files.

Here is my code :

```
kafkaStreamDf
  .select(col("topic"), col("timestamp"), date_format(current_timestamp(), "HHddMMyyyy").alias("date"))
  .repartition(col("date"))
  .writeStream.format("parquet")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("path", "/usr/data/kafkaStream")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")  
  .partitionBy("date")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
)
```

All the data are stored in /usr/data/kafkaStream/date=HHddMMyyyy as I wanted.
But I don't get why spark wrote the output data into multiple files, whereas the dataframe is partitionned by "date" and repartitionned with the same column. I'm using spark 3.0.1.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Is your `date` column formatted to include the hour as `HHddMMyyyy` ? Can you share a sample value from your df?

Comment: Can you clarify why you expected one file per date? Multiple files per partition is expected behavior until you coalese _each partition_

Comment: @ggordon Here is a sample of df column values:
 
`|topic_name|2021-08-12 14:24:55.299|1412082021|`

@OneCricketeer we want to have a single file per hour (or possibly one large file per day).  I tried to apply **coalese(1)** to **kafkaStreamDf** and partition data by **date** column. So I expected to have one file per **date** value. But instead, Spark writes multiple files.